# H12 error when attempting to run Node.js Express MongoDB app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

**The Problem**

Hello all, unfortunately I am stuck with an issue when after deploying my Node.js Express and MongoDB app to Heroku. The app works just fine on my computer but I am receiving a H12 error in the Heroku logs.  Here's the error for reference:

```
2021-08-19T16:20:26.186995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=accp-clean-blog-app.herokuapp.com request_id=222fe564-d711-4b62-b13c-272290bf0de5 fwd="174.246.20.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

**What I've done so far**

I have searched extensively here on Stack Overflow and tried multiple solutions... at first I thought it was a MongoDB connection error and I hadn't added my MongoDB url to the `config vars` on Heroku.  So I changed that and I am still receiving the same error.  I have my MongoDB url and port with `process.env` notations.  I also have a Procfile with `web: node index.js`.  Attached below is my `index.js`:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const newPostController = require('./controllers/newPost')
const homeController = require('./controllers/home')
const storePostController = require('./controllers/storePost')
const getPostController = require('./controllers/getPost')
const validateMiddleware = require('./middleware/validationMiddleware')
const newUserController = require('./controllers/newUser')
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser')
const loginController = require('./controllers/login')
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')
const authMiddleware = require('./middleware/authMiddleware')
const redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware = require('./middleware/redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware')
const logoutController = require('./controllers/logout')
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const app = new express()
const ejs = require('ejs')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use denotes Express.js middleware
//Middleware are functions that Express executes in the order they are declared and they
//can make changes to the request and response objects
//When a request comes in to the server, Express will execute all of the app.use middleware
//on the request, before completing the request and sending the response.

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))

app.use(fileUpload);

app.use('/posts/store', validateMiddleware)
app.use(flash());

//GET requests simply resources/retrieves the requested information from the server
//POST requests are used to request an addition to the server, such as a blog entry, a photo,
//signing up for an account, or buying an item. POST is used to create records on servers.

app.get('/', homeController)
app.get('/post:id', getPostController)
app.get('/posts/new', authMiddleware, newPostController);
app.post('/posts/store', authMiddleware, storePostController)
app.get('/auth/register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, newUserController)
app.post('/users/register', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, storeUserController)
app.get('/auth/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController)
app.post('/user/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginUserController)
app.get('/auth/logout', logoutController)
app.use((req,res) => res.render('notfound'));

//the global variable logged in is accessible to all of the EJS files. This will make
//modifications to the navigational bar when a user is logged in

global.loggedIn = null;

app.use("*", (req,res,next) => {
    loggedIn = req.expressSession.userId;
    next();
})

let port = process.env.PORT;
if(port == null || port == ""){
    port = 4000;
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port: ' + port)
})


/*const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
*/
const db = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(db, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
      });
      console.log("MongoDB is Connected...");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };

  //mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Clearly, there something I'm missing here...and I'm just not seeing it.  Thank you in advance for your help :)

You can also find my GitHub repository for this [project here](https://github.com/ACupOfCodePodcast/Clean-Blog-App)

And the Heroku app [here](https://accp-clean-blog-app.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I should note here too that I understand this error to be a runtime error and that Heroku times out at 30 seconds.

Comment: If your mongo db is hosted by atlas, make sure you allow access from everywhere (security -> network access -> 0.0.0.0/0 ) - I'm assuming you are not using Heroku private spaces.

Comment: Hi and thank you for that - I should have mentioned that in my first post….I did allow access from everywhere when I set up MongoDB atlas. You are correct, I am not using Heroku private spaces

Comment: Does anyone think this error could have anything to do with my internet connection? Just curious as I live in a rural community with not great internet service…

Comment: Also, I’m working out of Greg Lim’s book ‘Beginning Node.js, Express and MongoDB Development’.  The code here in my repository is exactly what he teaches out of the book, as I was trying to learn and understand Node and MongoDB better. Is anyone familiar with the book?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It has gone for me when I changed the connection string with those for driver version 2.2.12 or later (which doesn't start with mongodb+srv:).